# Accessing a property of an object inside an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have some JSON that I have specifically put inside a variable for this question.

Here is my json:

```
{"json":{"-K-dxZZVLv4N11BQ-tEJ":{"AssetID":1},"-K-dxwm5y1hVS68GyMhN":{"AssetID":2}}}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
var url = "https://rbxjson.firebaseio.com/catalog.json";
var recent;
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
recent = Object.keys(json["json"])[0]["AssetID"];
alert(recent);
});
```

I'm trying to access the value of "AssetID" in "{"AssetID":1}" but I tried the above code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Why `Object.keys`??? Use `json.json['-K-dxZZVLv4N11BQ-tEJ'].AssetID`

Comment: aint work bro remember there is more before assetid

Comment: @Tushar - I **want** to interpret as me not knowing the ['-K-dxZZVLv4N11BQ-tEJ']. That is a random key that appears from Firebase that I am not sure how to get rid of. it would be easier without it

Comment: Oliver, please add the same in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns a list of string keys.
Those, aren't actually parts of the object, but just the names.

Secondly, note that you have an object in an object. in order to access the subobject, duplicate `json` to `json.json`.

In order to access the content in that key, use `json[key]`, this way:

```
var url = "https://rbxjson.firebaseio.com/catalog.json";
var recent;
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    var key = Object.keys(json.json)[0]
    recent = json.json[key]["AssetID"];
    alert(recent);
});
```

In order to find the last asset, go ahead and use:

```
// ...
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    var keys = Object.keys(json.json);
    var key = keys[keys.length - 1];
    //...
});
```

Ob a side note, you may want to rename `json` to `res` or `result`, making the structure more intuitive: `result.json`, like that:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (res) {
    var key = Object.keys(res.json)[0]
    recent = res.json[key]["AssetID"];
    alert(recent);
});
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct, but how do I find the last assetid now (of json obcjet)

Comment: Oh @ my last comment. i don't just mean stick [1] instead of [0]. i mean always depending on the size

Comment: I have updated the answer with your request: how to fins last key. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's quite an odd structure, because the *keys* seem like they're quite variable. But here's how you'd access them (you're quite close with your `Object.keys`):

```js
var json = {"json":{"-K-dxZZVLv4N11BQ-tEJ":{"AssetID":1},"-K-dxwm5y1hVS68GyMhN":{"AssetID":2}}};
Object.keys(json.json).forEach(function(name) {
  snippet.log(name + ": " + json.json[name].AssetID);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I've shown a loop there because you're dealing with an object, not an array. Traditionally, JavaScript objects have no order to their properties (although this changed in ECMAScript 2015), and even though ECMAScript 2015 changed that, I don't think *JSON* (the format you're using on the wire) has any property order.

Comment: Have you used Firebase before? I don't know how to get rid of the key atthe start: ['-K-dxZZVLv4N11BQ-tEJ']. help please

Comment: @OliverTwist: I don't know what you mean by "get rid of the key at the start."

Comment: Well, I used the Firebase write API to add it, and when I do add the "{"AssetID":1}" Object for some reason it adds a key to it